# Cant unbind or blacklist driver

Tags: drivers, kernel, qemu, 15.10

Hello I want to unbind or blacklist my graphicscard driver. Currently it uses the noveau driver but I cant blacklist it when I type `blacklist noveau` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and then reboot, nothing happens. I even cant bind it to pci-stub. This seems to have something to do with the new kernel 4.2 in Ubuntu 15.10...

Edit:

Relevant part of the output of `lspci -vnn` after adding `vfio-pci.ids=10de:1184,10de:0e0a` and `intel_iommu=on` to `/etc/default/grub`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 770] [10de:1184] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:360c]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
Memory at e8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: nouveau

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller [10de:0e0a] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:360c]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
Memory at f7080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to downgrade your kernel a bit. Something in 4.2 broke it, I am currently on 4.1.6

[Linux 4.1.6-1 -> 4.2.2-1 breaks PCI passthrough in QEMU/KVM](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=203240)

Edit: I have upgraded to 4.3-rc7 and the issues seems to have been fixed by this patch. I would assume it will be backported eventually.

[IOMMU Fixes for Linux v4.3-rc7](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/iommu/2015-October/014789.html)

Comment: Thank you, now I use Debian as server like thing and have Ubuntu as a vm.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's not enough to just add "nouveau" to blacklist. You also need to update initrd:

```
update-initramfs -k all -u
```

This will update it for all kernels, but you can also update only kernel you currently running:

```
update-initramfs -u -k `uname -r`
```

Also if you planning to use QEMU with VFIO and not legacy "pci-assign" then with kernel 4.1 or newer it's possible to bind devices directly to VFIO-PCI driver:

```
vfio-pci.ids=1002:6719,1002:aa80
```

So you don't need to use pci-stub anymore. Of course don't forget that you need to update grub configuration once you saved /etc/default/grub:

```
update-grub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it still doesn't work with my graphic card. The audio part of the graphics card it now sucessfully bound to vfio-pci drivers but my graphics card remains to be bound to nouveau driver.

Comment: Are you sure both PCI IDs you you put there are valid? Anyway you can always go into tty console and manually bind/unbind GPU from driver as long as X server stopped.  You can look how [into my configuration example](https://gist.github.com/ArseniyShestakov/dc152d080c65ebaa6781#file-vfio-setup-sh).

Comment: Well now I use Debian 8.1 with kernel 3.16 and installed Ubuntu 15.10 in one of my VMs.